# Strange behavior jquery sortable on scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I'm building the front-end part of an admin project. Right now I'm working on a page overview where you can sort the pages (as a list). I'm using jquery plugin nestedSortable, [from here](https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable), to get the tree view functionality.

My problem: If the page has been scrolled the item you start dragging/sorting is positioned the amount of pixel scrolled down from the mouse instead of at the mouse as it should be (dragging/sorting before scrolling).

My options for the sorting list looks like this:

```
var ns = $('.sortable-list').nestedSortable({
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  handle: '.handle',
  helper: 'clone',
  items: 'li',
  opacity: .9,
  placeholder: 'sort-placeholder',
  revert: 250,
  tabSize: 15,
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  toleranceElement: '> div',
  maxLevels: 4,
  isTree: true,
  expandOnHover: 700,
  startCollapsed: true,
  stop: function() {
    updateList();
    setTimeout(updateList, 100);
  }
});
```

[**I also made a codepen thats illustrate my problem.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjbPjy)

Do anyone know how to fix this problem? - Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this was a bug in the nestedSortable library. There's a commit on the git repository that says it should fix that bug (https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable/commits/2.0alpha), so try upgrading to the latest version and see if that fixes your problem.

UPDATE: In fact, modifying your CodePen to use the latest version of the file works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNPWKX.

The nestedSortable source file I used for the CodePen is:

```
<script src='http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js'></script>
```

Comment: You sir, are now my new farvorite person in this world. Thank you a millions times.